# Fetching data from database and passing to another form

Tags: c#

I want to store integer value in label and to pass to another form. But value gets passed but it passes `system.data.dataset`. Below is my code. Please help me with this.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select balance from customer where namee='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "loki");
label4.Text = ds.ToString();
options frm = new options(label4.Text);
frm.Show();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Set *modifier* of TextBox to *public* and write this *code* in second form.

Comment: You have assign System.Data.Dataset to label and pass it to another form

Comment: You're setting `ds.ToString()`. If you want to retrieve data from the database, you should browse on the dataset tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select balance from customer where namee='" 
                        + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
label4.Text = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to pass the balance field value in the label.Text

Instead of this

```
label4.Text = ds.ToString();
```

You have do it this way

```
label4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows["balance"].ToString();
```

> Mind you as it will be stored as string in the Text property of the label, 
>   so when you retrieve it out on another form you
>   will have to convert it to int using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: there is error coming that is cannot convert from string to int and system.data.datarowcollection.this[this] has some invalid argument

Comment: @user1526527 please show me the full exception and on what line of code

Comment: code is not submitted in this

Comment: con.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select balance from customer where namee='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
                object balance=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                label4.Text = balance.ToString();

                
                 options frm = new options(label4.Text);


                frm.Show();
                con.Close();

Comment: this is codepease help me out

Comment: @user1526527 is the column name correct in your sql " where namee" do you think it should be " where name"

Comment: i want to just take out varchar type value from table and pass it to options form.....

Comment: @user1526527 so the column balance is an varchar type on customer table, please tell what sort of value it already have in sql table e.g. 10.00 or £10.00

Comment: problem iss solved......i use string label4.text=cmd1.executescaler().to string();

Answer (score 1):

You want to get a 'scalar' value instead of a dataset.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select balance from customer where namee='" 
                        + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
object balance = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
label4.Text = balance.ToString();

options frm = new options(label4.Text);
frm.Show();
con.Close();
```

Comment: con.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select balance from customer where namee='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
                object balance=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                label4.Text = balance.ToString();

                
                 options frm = new options(label4.Text);


                frm.Show();
                con.Close();